# How TO reinstate gitignore files

Tags: reactjs, express, github, mern, gitignore

I recently downloaded a zipped file from github.
I notice that this file has a gitignore so not all of the features work, is there anyway that I could extract data from the gitignore file so that this app would work with all its features

So the file-based code for administrative purposes,  but I think because the gitignore probably has the .env file I am unable to have administrative access

Answer (score 1):

You can't "reinstate" ignored files becaue there is nothing to reinstate since it was ignored. Instead, you need to read the documentation (if there is any) or the code to figure out how you set up the appropriate files for configuration, such as `.env`.

The exact details are entirely dependant on the exact project. Without a link to the project, I cannot help any further.